# How to get a Head of the Serpent

Tags: everquest

What is the spawn timer of [Wraith of a Shissar](http://everquest.allakhazam.com/db/npc.html?id=5152) in Plane of Fear? It looks like it used to be [7 days](http://everquest.allakhazam.com/wiki/EQ:Respawn_Timers), and then [reduced on TLP servers](https://forums.daybreakgames.com/eq/index.php?threads/game-update-notes-july-1-2015.224468/#post-3279303).

Answer (score 1):

From developer Jonathan Caraker in [this post](https://dgcissuetracker.com/browse/EQ-303):

> ...there is a random delay of up to 3 days before the Wraith of a Shissar NPC will spawn, and she's only up for 2 hours before despawning, after which it's another 1.5+ day delay before respawning.

Comment: Holy crap! Thanks. Did you get the Necromancer badge?

Comment: lol, no. That requires five votes. :)